# How to properly adjust width and size to image rendered with apex:outputField

Tags: visualforce, pdf, image-formula

I am developing a visualforce renderAs pdf. One of the requirements is to show a couple of images stored in formula fields in Product2 objects (formula using IMAGE()). This means that querying those fields returns img tags. I understand that those img tags returned by the query already have width and height set (because that is used in page layouts), but I need to reduce the size of the rendered image to fit on the PDF.

```
<apex:outputField value="{!data.producto.Planta__c}"/>
```

This renders the image, but on the size specified on the formula. How can I target those images on my CSS, to override the width and height? I've seen some solutions but for rich text area fields, and not IMAGE(). I tried styling the outputField itself (I didn't expect it to work). Also tried limiting the td parent tag, but had no success.

Any help would be appreciated! I don't understand very well how outputField works in this case.